# Converting numbers to a single format in C#

Tags: c#, number-formatting, cultureinfo

I have the following case, from the client side I am getting a double value in a string, this can either be in 'en-GB' format or 'de' format, i.e 123.10 or 123,10. However I need to convert both these number to 123.10. i.e I tried writing the following test using NumberFormatInfo, however it does not pass:

```
var format = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberGroupSeparator = ",", NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };

        var a = Double.Parse("23000.10", format);
        var b = Double.Parse("23000,10", format);

        Assert.AreEqual(a,b);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You merely confirmed that the strings produce different values in en-GB.  You already knew that, not much point in testing it.  Change to Assert.AreNotEqual() to get the test to pass.

Comment: right... how do i make them produce the same value without manually checking for a comma and replacing it with a decimal.?

Comment: `Random.Next` would be more readable way to produce random results from user input. `23.000,44` should give you some interesting results... There is really no way to do what you want without knowing the input format (Culture in .Net terms).

Comment: I added an answer that fix your situation, is not the best way to do, but always change the , for . in your string. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i make them produce the same value

You can't without knowing the context - if you don't know the context of the input there's no way to distinguish if `123,456` means `123456` or `123.456`.

If your input never contains thousands separators (which seems to be the case from your example), then replacing commas with periods is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is an issue with this kind of conversion.

Anyway, in some project I used the following code:

```
double a = 0;
double b = 0;

double.TryParse("23000.10".Replace(",","."), out a);
double.TryParse("23000,10".Replace(",", "."), out b);

Assert.AreEqual(a,b);
```

Isn't the best way to do but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify culture info, try with this:

```
var cultureInfo1 = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
var cultureInfo2 = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

var a = Double.Parse("1200,00", cultureInfo1);
var b = Double.Parse("1200.00", cultureInfo2);

Assert.AreEqual(a,b);
```